# How do I fix incomplete certificate chain in nginx

Tags: android, ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, coronasdk

I'm using a package called coroinium cloud and I have recently set up ssl. Coronium cloud is a server package for apps developed with corona SDK. It uses nginx as the server for the package. There is a control panel that you connect to through your browser which loads fine and firefox says the certificate is trusted. However it does not work on the app but instead shows an error saying the certificate is not trusted (CertPathValidatorException on android). I used a tool by digicert to check the ssl configuration:

[screenshot of digicert test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyTB3.png)

There were instructions by the creator of coronium cloud on how to set it up of which all I followed. I got the certificate from startssl.com and used there Nginx certificate. Does anyone know how I can fix this issue as it is holding me back from developing other features as I now can't use any part of my app till this is fixed.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me

Answer (score 1):

You should use the certificate chain provided by your Certificate Authority, in the same time than your certificate, and follow the nxinx documentation:

https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/configuring_https_servers.html#chains

> cat www.example.com.crt bundle.crt > www.example.com.chained.crt

And in your server block:

> ssl_certificate     www.example.com.chained.crt;

Comment: I have used the certificate bundle provided by startcom but it seems to imply that part of the certificate is missing. I'm not famiular with ngnix as it was a software bundle and all the configuration was done by an automated tool. Is it the configuration or the certifcate at fault?

Comment: I have this configured. Could it be the certificate that is the problem?

Comment: A intermediate certificate is missing in the file specified by ssl_certificate. That file is supposed to contain the list of certificate starting by your CA, the intermediate, and then your certificate. Your file contain some intermediate and your certificate, but the beginning is missing.

Comment: I think i found the problem.  In the ngnix config file there is an inlude to a file in the packages setting. The file name is wrong. However I don't have permission to edit it. Do you know how I can grant the permission?

Comment: I used the file which was specifically created for nginx which was a bundle of them both. I would have thought the bundle created for nginx would contain all required certificates

Comment: Yes. https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=server.iamsmalltech.com

Comment: You send your certificate and the certificate of your CA but not the intermediaries. And you should read the red/orange warnings too!

Comment: I shall try and bundle them togehter